# “app not installed” when trying to uninstall app after it's installed via Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have meizu m2, (Android version 5.1, and Flyme version 4.5.31) and I run the app on my phone, (with the "run" button, not export apk file -> install via file manager) and the app works fine, but when i'm trying to uninstall the app, it's does problems.

After I uninstalled the app, (settings -> apps -> "test1" (app name) -> uninstall) it not exists anymore on the phone, but in the apps list, (in the settings) the app is still exists, but with a label "not installed" - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6aCC.jpg)

(the app is "test1")

How can I completely remove the app? (the app is just a basic app from the examples templates, nothing special)
And my pc os is Linux Fedora 22 (if this matter)

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
When i'm trying to install the apk via the file manager, (on the phone), after I did build -> generate signed apk`, so I get this error - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHTwH.jpg)
(the "app not installed" message appears after I click "install")

And this may be helpfull:
I found some websites, that they say to try with adb (to delete some file (which need root access, (I think) so need the adb)) but I don't know how to use adb at all.. (I don't know even how to connect to my phone)

Comment: Did you try closing that settings window, or rebooting the device?

Comment: yes, of course..
And I have 2 apps like this, one is just from now, (few hours), and the second is about 6 months, so reboot is not helping (because I rebooted a lot of times in those months)
And i've also tried some apps like "clean master", to clean old / cache files, and it also didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

1. On your phone, enable developer options (look up how to do this)
2. Enable USB debugging from developer options
3. Connect your phone to your PC with a USB cable
4. on your pc type "adb uninstall [package name]"

The package name will be something like com.company.appname.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem few week ago.
Just Power Off your smartphone and Restart it again.
It will  gone from the app list.